# Lua - slow bytcode

Tags: lua, bytecode

i have 3 files x.lua, y.lua and main.lua. These files doing some mathematics operations (increment and decrement number). When i run the command

`lua main.lua`

is much faster than

`luac -o main.luac -s  x.lua y.lua main.lua`

Please can you help me why is bytecode slower?

Comment: We need examples files that show the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that `main.lua` does `dofile("x.lua")` or `require"x"` and the same for `y.lua`.

In that case, the second form runs `x.lua` and `y.lua` twice.

Answer (score 1):

They are very different operations:

1. `lua main.lua`: this does

   - reads 3 files,
   - compiles them to bytecode in memory and
   - executes a subset of their bytecode;
2. `luac -o main.luac -s  x.lua y.lua main.lua`: this does:

   - reads 3 files (the 2 read by main are not read since main is not executed),
   - compiles them to bytecode in memory, then
   - saves three of them to one file on disk.

Writing a file (operation 2) is a slow operation, involving disk access, dumping memory chunks etc; it will be significantly slower than executing some bytecode (operation 1), unless latter is compute intensive.

Comment: Thank you, and please how can i make one bytecode from 3 other files without lost speed

Comment: @lhf Ah yes, because the 2 other reads only occur as part of the execution. Updated.